# Recycler view cant wrap height of its children items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, listitem

Am trying to use RecyclerView but it cant show all the items of its children, but i want to show all the items [image: This is how the lists looks like]

Comment: @kishore actually i dont think its a xml problem because am using it in a ListView and its working fine showing all the children

Comment: Are you using a fixed height for the items?

Comment: post main and adapter `xml` without code how can we predict what's problem

Comment: @Rami am not using a fixed height

Answer (score 0):

The list Items were wrapped in a Linear Layout i changed it and wrapped it in a Relative layout and it solved the problem